# How to format words in an other language?

Tags: discussion, formatting

I use "quotes" since they are quick to type and easier to see than *italic*. Is there a specific rule (or should there be a specific rule) about this in order to improve parsing and readability?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the function. For the literal text, eg a sample sentence, the linguistic convention is using italics. If you're talking about the meaning, eg to paraphrase something, but not referring to the actual words, then you would use quotes.